# How to speed up android adb push/pull via USB OTG

Tags: android, performance, usb, adb

I am in a project need adb push/pull from our phone to another phone via USB OTG. Our platform is based on QualComm 615/Android 4.4.4 and the speeds are slow, about 1366 K/s and 1766 K/s, however we need 3M/s.

At first we think is our hardware problem, so we test the USB otg by only copy file to/from a U-Disk by ES, the speeds are 4.5M/s and 20M/s. And the 5V voltage is stable, so the USB link layer seems not the bottle neck

We also compare our platform to other QualComm platforms, both QualComm 800 and QualComm 610 has the speeds around 3M/s, so the major frequence seems not the bottle neck, either.

For our platform, is there any way to speed up or any direction ? We can modify our android code and configuration, Thanks in advance. [OTG adb Comparing to U-Disk copy and other platforms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoVvl.png)

Comment: Your problem is `adb`, most likely. `adb` is slow everywhere. The upcoming version of `adb` that is part of Android Studio 2.0 is supposed to be substantially faster.

Comment: You are trying to use `adb` for some other purpose than it was designed for. Just activate the `rmnet` interface on the device side and use that for data transfer.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes, after looking into this I also found adb might not be proper solution. But it's our partener's framework, which use adb forward for socket communication between apps in host and device sides seperately. We have the total control in host side under adb, so want to solve the problem there :(

Comment: @AlexP. rmnet appears to be specific to qualcomm chipsets, at least from my initial searches on it.